# persist bidirectional relationship ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have these classes:

```
public class AllegationContent {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected long id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
    private AllegationItem allegationItem;

    @DatabaseField()
    protected String content;
    ...
}
```

And:

```
public class AllegationItem {
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    protected ForeignCollection<AllegationContent> allegationContent;
    ...
}
```

How can I persist both?
I am trying this:

```
    allegationContentDao = getAllegationContentDao();   
    AllegationContent allegationContent = new AllegationContent(); 
    allegationContent.setContent("allegation content");     
    allegationContentDao.create(allegationContent);

    allegationItemDao = getAllegationItemDao();
    AllegationItem allegationItem = new AllegationItem();
    AllegationContent allegationContent2 = allegationContentDao.queryForSameId(allegationContent);  //is that wrong?
    allegationItem.getAllegationContent().add(allegationContent2);
    allegationItemDao.create(allegationItem);
```

but I got this error:

> 04-24 10:41:57.128: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.project/br.com.project.DaoTestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: So what line is the NPE happening?  Have you tried debugging your code to figure out what which objects on that line are null?  There is not enough information for anyone to figure out where in your code you are trying to access your null pointer.

Comment: I'm not finding the line. I removed ForeignCollection from AllegationItem and try just create one AllegationItem, and got this error: "INFO/Database(1024): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ")": syntax"
I can't understand... AllegationItem have only the field Id.

Comment: Sorry, just too little information for us to help.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in ORMLite and Android =/
Can I edit this post adding more information?

Comment: I would suggest that you learn how to use the debugger.  Step through you code until you get the exception.  Here's a good video on the subject: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A

Comment: I solved. The table can't create because don't have atributes, only id. The NPE happen because getAllegationContent return null, so first I need create a ForeignCollection list, set using setAllegationContent and then get.

Comment: If you solved this then you should answer your own question for posterity and accept you own question as the answer.  Either that or delete the question.

Comment: @Gray, have a way to talk directly with you? I'm not getting a way to create a ForeignCollection (I know it's a interface) to pass to set method. I try instance a LazyForeignCollecion, but I can't understand his parameters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10503/discussion-between-gray-and-munir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. The table can't create because don't have atributes, only id (what's another problem). The NPE happen because getAllegationContent return null, so first I need create a ForeignCollection list, set using setAllegationContent and then get.